# Line integral $\int_C(3x + \sin(y)) ds$ where $C$ is line segment from $(1,2)$ to $(5,4)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

How to calculate the line integral $$
\int_C(3x + \sin(y)) \,ds
$$
where $C$ is line segment from $(1,2)$ to $(5,4)$?

#### Progress

I know $r(t) = \langle 1+4t,2+2t\rangle$   from $(0,1)$ so I have an integral from 0 to 1 of (???) dt

How do I take my original integral and parametrization to make a new integral?

I know $ds = \sqrt{(dx/ds)^2 + (dy/ds)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

First, your $ds = \sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2}\ dt$. Then as you have already found
\begin{align}
x(t) &= 1 + 4t\\
y(t) &= 2 + 2t
\end{align}
What is $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$? Once you have that you can plug what you know into your integral
$$
\int_0^1[3x(t) + \sin(y(t))]ds = 40.7803
$$